# How can I create bottom corners curved button?

Tags: css, user-interface, button, frontend

I want to create a curvedbutton like this. How can I do this?
[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
```

You can check W3schools for a better answer: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp.